The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used
A password reset email is sent. When I access the link I have the possibility to change the password with another one. After typing the new password and pressing the button I receive the fallowing error:
The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used.
This is my password_reset_page.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';

final authProvider = Provider<FirebaseAuth>((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance);

class PasswordResetPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const PasswordResetPage({super.key});

  @override
  PasswordResetPageState createState() => PasswordResetPageState();
}

class PasswordResetPageState extends ConsumerState<PasswordResetPage> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  Timer? _debounce;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> _scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  Future<void> _sendPasswordResetEmail() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final FirebaseAuth auth = ref.read(authProvider);
      await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(
        email: _emailController.text,
        actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
          url: 'https://romexpo-mobile-app.web.app/reset_password.html?oobCode=%CODE%&lang=ro',
          handleCodeInApp: true,
        ),
      );
      _showDialog('Success', 'Password reset email sent. Please check your email.');
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      _showSnackbar(SnackBar(content: Text('Error: ${e.message}')));
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onResetButtonPressed() {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) return;

    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      _sendPasswordResetEmail();
    });
  }

  void _showSnackbar(SnackBar snackBar) {
    _scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.hideCurrentSnackBar();
    _scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  void _showDialog(String title, String content) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title),
          content: Text(content),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState?.hideCurrentSnackBar();
    });

    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: _scaffoldMessengerKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Reset Password')),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              _isLoading
                  ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _onResetButtonPressed,
                      child: const Text('Reset Password'),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _debounce?.cancel();
    _emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

This is my reset_password.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Resetați parola</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        input, button {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

        #message {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Resetați parola</h1>
        <form id="reset-password-form">
            <input type="password" id="new-password" placeholder="Noua parola" required>
            <button type="submit">Resetați Parola</button>
        </form>
        <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.8/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: ".........",
            authDomain: ".........",
            projectId: "........",
            storageBucket: ".........",
            messagingSenderId: "..........",
            appId: "........."
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        var auth = firebase.auth();

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            var oobCode = urlParams.get('oobCode');

            if (!oobCode) {
                showMessage('Codul este invalid sau lipseste din URL.', 'red');
                return;
            }

            document.getElementById('reset-password-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var newPassword = document.getElementById('new-password').value;

                auth.confirmPasswordReset(oobCode, newPassword)
                    .then(function () {
                        showMessage('Parola a fost resetată cu succes!', 'green');
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        handlePasswordResetError(error);
                    });
            });
        });

        function showMessage(message, color) {
            var messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');
            messageDiv.style.color = color;
            messageDiv.textContent = message;
        }

        function handlePasswordResetError(error) {
            let errorMessage = 'A apărut o eroare: ';
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'auth/expired-action-code':
                    errorMessage += 'Codul a expirat. Vă rugăm să solicitați un alt e-mail pentru resetarea parolei.';
                    break;
                case 'auth/invalid-action-code':
                    errorMessage += 'Codul este invalid. Vă rugăm să verificați linkul din e-mail sau să solicitați un alt e-mail pentru resetarea parolei.';
                    break;
                case 'auth/user-disabled':
                    errorMessage += 'Acest cont a fost dezactivat.';
                    break;
                case 'auth/user-not-found':
                    errorMessage += 'Nu există niciun utilizator asociat cu acest cod.';
                    break;
                default:
                    errorMessage += error.message;
                    break;
            }
            showMessage(errorMessage, 'red');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

And this is the link that I set up in the password reset email template in firebase: href='https://romexpo-mobile-app.web.app/reset_password.html?oobCode=%CODE%&lang=ro'
Using this method I am trying to use an alternative to the firebase UI reset password that has only one rule : minimum 6 characters, also I am using this method to avoid using deep links.

now when i am using href="https://romexpo-mobile-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=AIzaSyA_FE-RD6fU-TflGnZpQD6LWVLygZxjvyc&mode=resetPassword&oobCode=%LINK%&continueUrl=https://romexpo-mobile-app.web.app/reset_password.html?lang=ro" I receive  Try resetting your password again
The password reset request has expired or the link has already been used
